# Having problem running python code (Markov Chain project)

Tags: python, pycharm

I just got into python a few weeks ago and I've been learning the language using the PyCharm software.
I was hoping to use the following code for a project:
https://github.com/eohomegrownapps/markov-music

I installed the required library, and inserted a midi file in the mentioned folder (the input folder). I'm using the following midi file:
http://www.bachcentral.com/invent/invent1.mid

Once I run the code, nothing appears in the 'compositions' folder. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'll post a screenshot of the code below.

Thanks a million in advance

[Updated Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vprlQ.png)

```
import random
import midi
import datetime


class Markov(object):
    """docstring for Markov"""

    def __init__(self, order=2):
        super(Markov, self).__init__()
        self.order = order
        self.chain = {}

    def add(self, key, value):
        if self.chain.has_key(key):
            self.chain[key].append(value)
        else:
            self.chain[key] = [value]

    def load(self, midifile):
        pattern = midi.read_midifile(midifile)
        # track = pattern[1]
        for track in pattern:
            noteslist = []
            curoffset = 0
            for i in track:
                if i.name == "Note On" and i.data[1] != 0:
                    note = (i.data[0], i.data[1], i.tick + curoffset)
                    # note = (i.data[0],i.data[1],i.tick)
                    noteslist.append(note)
                    curoffset = 0
                else:
                    curoffset += i.tick
            if len(noteslist) > self.order:
                for j in range(self.order, len(noteslist)):
                    t = tuple(noteslist[j - self.order:j])
                    print t
                    print noteslist[j]
                    self.add(t, noteslist[j])
            else:
                print "Corpus too short"

    def generate(self, length, filename):
        pattern = midi.Pattern()
        # Instantiate a MIDI Track (contains a list of MIDI events)
        track = midi.Track()
        # Append the track to the pattern
        pattern.append(track)

        tick = 0
        currenttuple = random.choice(self.chain.keys())
        prevnote = False
        for i in range(0, self.order):
            if prevnote != False:
                on = midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=tick, velocity=0, pitch=prevnote)
                track.append(on)
            on = midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=0, velocity=currenttuple[i][1], pitch=currenttuple[i][0])
            track.append(on)
            tick = currenttuple[i][2]
            prevnote = currenttuple[i][0]
        result = random.choice(self.chain[currenttuple])
        # print currenttuple
        for i in range(1, length):
            for j in range(0, self.order):
                if prevnote != False:
                    if tick > 5000:
                        tick = 5000
                    on = midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=tick, velocity=0, pitch=prevnote)
                    track.append(on)
                on = midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=0, velocity=currenttuple[j][1], pitch=currenttuple[j][0])
                track.append(on)
                tick = currenttuple[j][2]
                prevnote = currenttuple[j][0]

            currenttuple = list(currenttuple)
            currenttuple.pop(0)
            currenttuple.append(result)
            currenttuple = tuple(currenttuple)
            if self.chain.has_key(currenttuple):
                result = random.choice(self.chain[currenttuple])
            else:
                result = random.choice(self.chain[random.choice(self.chain.keys())])
        # Add the end of track event, append it to the track
        eot = midi.EndOfTrackEvent(tick=1)
        track.append(eot)
        # Print out the pattern
        print pattern
        # Save the pattern to disk
        midi.write_midifile(filename + ".mid", pattern)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory = "compositions"
    musicdir = "input"

    musicdir += "/"
    logname = directory + "/" + "{:%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S}_genmusic".format(datetime.datetime.now())

    m = Markov(3)
    print "Loading music"
    inp = raw_input('Name of midi file to load or g to generate: ')
    while inp != "g":
        try:
            m.load(musicdir + inp)
        except Exception as e:
            print "File not found or corrupt"
        inp = raw_input('Name of midi file to load or g to generate: ')
    print "Done"
    print m.chain
    m.generate(1000, logname)
```

Comment: Did you install [python-midi](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi) as required by [markov-music](https://github.com/eohomegrownapps/markov-music)?

Comment: Yes I did, Jamie!

Comment: It's helpful when the person asking the question pastes the code.

Comment: Apologies. I added the code. It's my first time posting on this website so please bear with me!

Comment: Looking at the traceback on your screenshot, it looks like  text.py script is not loading the split_into_sentences package. That said, you should not have spaces in any of your project path files or directories, so you should rename "Markov Chain" to "MarkovChain". LInux is not WIndows.

Comment: Was the stack trace removed from the post? I don't see it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Jamie. I updated the Screenshot because I created a new project with no space in names. So the error is gone now, but again, the program runs the code and nothing happens without an error...

Comment: The latest screenshot shows it prompting you for the name of the midi file. Are you typing it in?

Comment: You mean typing it into the console in front of 'Name of midi file to load or g to generate: ' right? If so, I did try that and it gives me the following error: Name of midi file to load or g to generate: test
File not found or corrupt